# Using a variable from a higher scope in a callback

Tags: rust

I am trying to use an object `mechanics` from the higher scope in a callback. To do that I tried to make object `mechanics` static.

```rust
pub fn main()
{
  let mut mechanics : &'static Mechanics = &'static mut Mechanics { val : 13. };
  let mut renderer = Render::new( "solution1".to_string() );
  renderer.f_on_update = Box::new( ||
  {
    println!( "mechanics.val : {}", mechanics.val )
  });
  renderer.update();
}

//

struct Mechanics
{
  val : f32,
}

//

struct Render
{
  name : String,
  f_on_update : Box< dyn Fn() >,
}

//

impl Render
{
  fn new( name : String ) -> Self
  {
    let f_on_update = || {};
    Self { name, f_on_update : Box::new( f_on_update ) }
  }
  fn update( &self )
  {
    (self.f_on_update)();
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
error: borrow expressions cannot be annotated with lifetimes
 --> src/static_solution_1.rs:4:44
  |
4 |   let mut mechanics : &'static Mechanics = &'static mut Mechanics { val : 13. };
  |                                            ^-------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                             |
  |                                             annotated with lifetime here
  |                                             help: remove the lifetime annotation
```

Changing to

```rust
let mut mechanics : &'static Mechanics = &Mechanics { val : 13. };
```

Gives the error:

```
error[E0597]: `mechanics` does not live long enough
  --> src/static_solution_1.rs:8:37
   |
6  |     renderer.f_on_update = Box::new( ||
   |                            -         -- value captured here
   |  __________________________|
   | |
7  | |   {
8  | |     println!( "mechanics.val : {}", mechanics.val )
   | |                                     ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  | |   });
   | |____- cast requires that `mechanics` is borrowed for `'static`
10 |     renderer.update();
11 |   }
   |   - `mechanics` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I do something wrong but have no clue where to look for an answer. Reading about static lifetime didn't help me to overcome the obstacle. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to make things static by lifetime annotation. Lifetimes describe what things already are, and don't tell them what they are supposed to be. Annotations are assertions, not commands.

For a thing to be `'static`, it has to be either a compile-time constant hardcoded in the executable or leaked memory. There is no other way to make something `'static`.

When you see the compiler demanding `'static`, it's trying to tell you that references are forbidden, and the code just won't work with local variables. In such a case, you need to move `||` closures and/or wrap data in `Arc` if you need to reference it from multiple places.

Without the `move` keyword, the closure expression infers how it captures each variable from its environment, preferring to capture by shared reference, effectively borrowing all outer variables mentioned inside the closure's body.

Some reading about a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/closure-expr.html) explaining that in greater detail.

Full solution:

```rust
fn main()
{
  let mut mechanics = Box::new( Mechanics { val : 13. } );
  let mut renderer = Render::new( "solution1".to_string() );
  renderer.f_on_update = Box::new( move ||
  {
    println!( "mechanics.val : {}", mechanics.val );
  });
  renderer.update();
}

//

struct Mechanics
{
  val : f32,
}

//

struct Render
{
  name : String,
  f_on_update : Box< dyn Fn() >,
}

//

impl Render
{
  fn new( name : String ) -> Self
  {
    let f_on_update = || {};
    Self { name, f_on_update : Box::new( f_on_update ) }
  }
  fn update( &self )
  {
    (self.f_on_update)();
  }
}
```

And a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a367f0f9a310166f746a72ff275f3e40) with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky aspect of rust, in order to do that the variable needs to be accessible for the lifetime of the program, meaning static. You already saw that just adding the static annotation gave you the 'borrow expressions cannot be annotated with lifetimes', so this can be resolved with a static keyword instead.
change

```
let mut mechanics : &'static Mechanics = &Mechanics { val : 13. };
```

to

```
 static mechanics:Mechanics =  Mechanics { val : 13. };
```